# Select a dropdown option using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have very little experience with javascript and I'm trying to use Chrome console to select an item in a dropdown list. I found a way how to set the index to another value, but it does not trigger the action that would happen if I clicked on it manually. I looked for an answer and tried `click()` and `focus()` functions, but nothing seems to trigger it.

```
document.getElementsByClassName("class-abc")[0].selectedIndex = 1
```

Update. @jeprubio, your answer works. Weirdly enough, it works even when I skip adding the event listener like in the code below.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("ui-pg-selbox")[0];
x.selectedIndex = 1;
x.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```
<select class="class-abc" role="listbox">
    <option role="option" value="10" selected="selected">10</option>
    <option role="option" value="20">20</option>
    <option role="option" value="50">50</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Show your html code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to trigger javascript when a dropdown option is selected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17921694/how-to-trigger-javascript-when-a-dropdown-option-is-selected)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events) apart from changing the `selectedIndex` to fire the `onChange` event as if you had done it manually:

```js
var select = document.getElementsByClassName("class-abc")[0];

select.addEventListener('change',function(){
   console.log('selected: ' + this.value);
});

select.selectedIndex = 1
select.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

```html
<select class="class-abc">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Comment: The code works without adding an event listener and just by using dispatchEvent line. What does `new Event('change')` mean in this case?

Comment: I put the listener just to console log that the `change` is triggered, to prove it. Without the dispatchEvent it's not triggered. If you look at the docs of [dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) you'll see that it needs an [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) object as parameter. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will help you !!!

```js
function submitss() {

  var temp = document.getElementById('country_drop_down_list').value
  var temp2 = temp.split('%%')
  console.log(temp2[0], temp2[1])
 }
```

```html
<select name="countryCode" id="country_drop_down_list" onchange="submitss()">

  <option value="Algeria%%213">Algeria (+213)</option>
  <option value="Andorra%%376">Andorra (+376)</option>
  <option value="Angola%%244">Angola (+244)</option>
  <option value="Anguilla%%1264">Anguilla (+1264)</option>
  <option value="Antigua%%1268">Antigua &amp; Barbuda (+1268)</option>
  <option value="Argentina%%54">Argentina (+54)</option>
  <option value="Armenia%%374">Armenia (+374)</option>
  <option value="Aruba%%297">Aruba (+297)</option>
 
</select>
```